# Removing Target _blank in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove the `target="_blank"` in the given code and also, show me how to add unordered list or ordered list. 
**Random Post example:** [Check the bottom of the page](http://themeten.blogspot.com/2016/07/love-is-light-in-darkness-of-life.html)

```
<div class='kotakleft'>
    <div class='boxleft'>
        <ul id='random-posts' />
        <script>
            var homePage = "http://www.example.com/",
                numPosts = 7;

            function randomPosts(a) {
                if (document.getElementById("random-posts")) {
                    var e = shuffleArray(a.feed.entry), title, link, img, content = "", ct = document.getElementById("random-posts");
                    for (var i = 0; i < numPosts; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < numPosts; j++) {
                            if (e[i].link[j].rel == "alternate") {
                                link = e[i].link[j].href;
                                break
                            }
                        }
                        var title = e[i].title.$t;
                        content += '<div class="random-posts"><li><a href="' + link + '" title="' + title + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a></li></div>'
                    }
                    ct.innerHTML = content
                }
            }

            function shuffleArray(arr) {
                var i = arr.length, j, temp;
                if (i === 0) return false;
                while (--i) {
                    j      = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                    temp   = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp
                }
                return arr
            }

            var random_post = document.createElement('script');
            random_post.src = homePage + '/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&orderby=published&max-results=999&callback=randomPosts';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(random_post);
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: cant you directly edit the code and remove?

Comment: Yeah, the easiest solution is to edit the code and save the file, job done :)

Comment: Any reason why you're running a script inside a div? What is the `<script>` tag doing here?

Comment: You want to make this code more complex by adding the script outside the div tag?

Comment: Just now, i looked target="_blank" and removed it from the code. But now i want to add the unordered or ordered list.. Is there any way to get this job done?

Comment: @FarooqAhmadBhat script tags scattered all over your document are not less complex, but way more difficult to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, you just need to change a few things:

```
    <div class='boxleft'>
        <ul id='random-posts' />
        <script>
            var homePage = "http://www.example.com/",
                numPosts = 7;

            function randomPosts(a) {
                if (document.getElementById("random-posts")) {
                    var e = shuffleArray(a.feed.entry), title, link, img, content = "", ct = document.getElementById("random-posts");
content = '<ul>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < numPosts; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < numPosts; j++) {
                            if (e[i].link[j].rel == "alternate") {
                                link = e[i].link[j].href;
                                break
                            }
                        }
                        var title = e[i].title.$t;
                        content += '<li><div class="random-posts"><a href="' + link + '" title="' + title + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a></div></li>'
                    }
content = '</ul>';
                    ct.innerHTML = content
                }
            }

            function shuffleArray(arr) {
                var i = arr.length, j, temp;
                if (i === 0) return false;
                while (--i) {
                    j      = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                    temp   = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp
                }
                return arr
            }

            var random_post = document.createElement('script');
            random_post.src = homePage + '/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&orderby=published&max-results=999&callback=randomPosts';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(random_post);
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```